# Setting the value of enabled for Triggers in Task scheduler to be enabled

Tags: powershell

I want to set the value "Enabled" in the task scheduler tasks for trigger to be True for all the tasks in my task scheduler.
The value is embedded inside XML.task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger  which is a value in the xml $task.XML. Somehow, I cannot retrieve the value from XML.task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger  shown below. I want to set this value to true and write it back to task scheduler so the tasks will be enabled if they are set to false. Any idea how I can achieve this?

```
$computerName = “localhost”
$TSchedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
$TSchedule.connect() 
$TasksList = $TSchedule.GetFolder('\Folder1').GetTasks(0)
foreach($Task in $TasksList) {     
$OutputObj = New-Object -TypeName PSobject
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TaskName -Value $Task.Name  
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IsEnabled -Value  $task.enabled 
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name XMLTrigger -Value $task.XML
$OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Trigger -Value $task.XML.task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger
if($TaskName) {                        
if($Task.Name -eq $TaskName) {
$OutputObj    }             } 
else { $OutputObj    
}                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

XML property of the $Task doesn't have setter, you can only read from there. But you can enable calendar trigger in different way. Here is how:

```
$computerName = “localhost”
$TSchedule = new-object -com("Schedule.Service")
$TSchedule.connect() 
$TasksFolder = $TSchedule.GetFolder('\Folder1')
$TasksList = $TasksFolder.GetTasks(0)
foreach($task in $TasksList) {
```

Th code above is almost identical to what you did, but I need $TasksFolder variable. Next line does not really create new task in task scheduler, explanation will follow

```
$new_task = $TSchedule.NewTask($null)
```

Then, we are getting xml content (note cast [xml])

```
$xml = [xml]$task.xml
```

In the following lines, we set calendar trigger enabled property to true (you can change any xml content in similar way here) and save it to our $new_task object.

```
$xml.task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger.Enabled = "true"
$new_task.XmlText = $xml.outerXml
```

Finally, we are registering our new task. And here we specify, that we want only to update it (third argument, 4 is for update. For details, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

```
    $TasksFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task.Name, $new_task, 4, $null, $null, 2, $null)
}
```

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:6 char:40
+    $TasksFolder.RegisterTaskDefinitions <<<< ($task.Name, $new_task, 4, $null, $null, 2, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (RegisterTaskDefinitions:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

I get this error for each task when it loops through all the tasks.

Comment: Make sure you copied everything from the answer. Code $TasksFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition is not on the 6-th line, as in your exception.

Comment: "Access is denied" — run PS as an administrator. "Property Enabled cannot be found" — make sure your task has calendar trigger, folder is correct, access is granted.

Comment: yes the task have calendar trigger and I am running as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Still have errors:

Property 'Enabled' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At line:4 char:36
+ $xml.task.Triggers.CalendarTrigger. <<<< Enabled = "true"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Enabled:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Exception calling "RegisterTaskDefinition" with "7" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
At line:6 char:37
+  $TasksFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition <<<< ($task.Name, $new_task, 4, $null, $null, 2, $null)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation

Answer (score 0):

I tried another way of doing it but it has no errors and the trigger does not modify from disabled to enabled. Not sure what is missing. :(

```
$ExportedTasks = Read-Host "Path to XML Files, Multiple files are supported"
$Machine = "localhost"
$user = "login"
$pass = "pass"
$ScheduledService = New-Object -ComObject("Schedule.Service")
$ScheduledService.connect("$Machine")
$ScheduledTaskFolder = $ScheduledService.GetFolder("\Folder1")
Get-Item $ExportedTasks\*.* | ForEach-Object{
$ScheduledTaskName = $_.Name.Replace('', '.xml')
$xml = [xml]$ScheduledTaskName.xml
$TaskXmlContent = $xml.outerXml
$Task = $ScheduledService.NewTask($null)
$Task.XmlText = $TaskXmlContent
$Task_Triggers = $Task.Triggers
$Task_Triggers.Enabled = $True
$ScheduledTaskFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition($ScheduledTaskName.Name, $Task, 4, $user, $pass, 2, $Task) 
}
```